# How to Fix 'PaginationModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class'

Tags: html, angular, angularjs, typescript

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PaginationModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PaginationModule.forRoot()
  ],
  
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

PaginationModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
I get an error.

i tried shutting down the server, i tried installing manually, i tried turning it on and off but it didn't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.